# Replace random word

Tags: mysql

I want replace random word in WordPress post. I have a code for MySQL.
This code working well:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'oldword','newword');
```

But when I want replace random in database like

```
replace(post_content,'oldword',rand('newword','google','stackoverflow','stackover'));
```

This code not working.

I don't know how use this code for random replace word.
**I want each occurrence of oldword to be replaced by a different word**

```
 Error

SQL query:

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =
REPLACE_RANDOM(post_content, 'oldword')

MySQL said: Documentation 

 #1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xA7\xDB\x8C\xD9\x86...' for column 'String' at row 1
```

Where is the problem?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Replace_Random$$
CREATE FUNCTION Replace_Random(String TEXT, Word TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE New TEXT DEFAULT '';
DECLARE Loc INT DEFAULT INSTR(String, Word);
DECLARE WLen INT DEFAULT Length(Word);
WHILE Loc DO
SET New = CONCAT(New, SUBSTR(String, 1, Loc-1), ELT(FLOOR(RAND()*5)+1, 'biterrr', 'stackoverflow', 'serress', 'ms-ms-ms', 'Nick'));
SET String = SUBSTR(String, Loc + WLen);
SET Loc = INSTR(String, Word);
END WHILE;
SET NEW = CONCAT(New, String);
RETURN New;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =
REPLACE_RANDOM(post_content, 'oldword');`
```

Comment: What is the data type of `post_content`?

Comment: wordpress table post-  just text

Comment: What is the character set of your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`ELT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) to pick a random value from a list of strings:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =
   REPLACE(post_content, 'oldword', ELT(FLOOR(RAND()*5)+1, 'hello', 'world', 'friend', 'tuesday', 'sunny'))
```

If you have a different number of strings in the list, just change the multiplier of `RAND()` from 5 to the number of strings.

**Update**

If you need to replace multiple occurrences of the string in a phrase with different words, you will need a stored function. This one will do the job:

```
DELIMITER \\
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Replace_Random\\
CREATE FUNCTION Replace_Random(String TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8, Word TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8)
RETURNS TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE New TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE Loc INT DEFAULT INSTR(String, Word);
    DECLARE WLen INT DEFAULT Length(Word);
    WHILE Loc DO
        SET New = CONCAT(New, SUBSTR(String, 1, Loc-1), ELT(FLOOR(RAND()*5)+1, 'hello', 'world', 'friend', 'tuesday', 'sunny'));
        SET String = SUBSTR(String, Loc + WLen);
        SET Loc = INSTR(String, Word);
    END WHILE;
    SET NEW = CONCAT(New, String);
    RETURN New;
END\\
DELIMITER ;

SELECT REPLACE_RANDOM('a string with oldword in it twice - oldword!', 'oldword');
```

Output (varies):

```
a string with sunny in it twice - tuesday!
a string with hello in it twice - friend!
```

Comment: tank u .cod working . but i have problome now. not work random for content . for example  if  use the **oldword**  twice  in content of post .

Comment: So you want each occurrence of `oldword` to be replaced by a different word?

Comment: yes i want each occurrence of oldword to be replaced by a different word.

Comment: Can you use stored procedures?

Comment: @HamedHabibi I have updated my answer with a function which will do what you want.

Comment: i have a little probleme pliz see my ask agian tank u

Comment: You might need to modify the function to support `utf8` input. See my edit, I think that should work.